# Excel - VB - Re-ordering /Renaming columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a Macro using VB in Excel to re-order /rename columns in a spreadsheet.

As well as re-ordering the columns, I also wish to change the titles of the column headers.

Eg: 'partner_accountname' -> 'Account Name'
    'partner_no' -> 'partner_number 
             ...and so on

I have been using the following Code to re-order the columns (which works fine) but I do not know how to re-name the column headers:

---

```
Sub MoveColumns()

' MoveColumns Macro
'
' Developer: Winko Erades van den Berg
' E-mail : winko@winko-erades.nl
' Developed: 03-10-2011
' Modified: 03-10-2011
' Version: 1.0
'
' Description: Rearrange columns in Excel based on column header

Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long

'Constant values
data_sheet1 = InputBox("Specify the name of the Sheet that needs to be reorganised:") 'Create Input Box to ask the user which sheet needs to be reorganised
target_sheet = "Final Report" 'Specify the sheet to store the results
iRow = Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'Determine how many rows are in use

'Create a new sheet to store the results
Worksheets.Add.Name = "Final Report"

'Start organizing columns
For iCol = 1 To Sheets(data_sheet1).UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Sets the TargetCol to zero in order to prevent overwriting existing targetcolumns
    TargetCol = 0

    'Read the header of the original sheet to determine the column order
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "billing_country" Then TargetCol = 7
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "partner_accountname" Then TargetCol = 2
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "partner_number" Then TargetCol = 3
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "pbl_due_date" Then TargetCol = 4
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "total_amount" Then TargetCol = 5
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "pb_payment_currency" Then TargetCol = 6
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "sort_code" Then TargetCol = 1
    If Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol).Value = "cda_number" Then TargetCol = 8

    'If a TargetColumn was determined (based upon the header information) then copy the column to the right spot
    If TargetCol <> 0 Then
        'Select the column and copy it
        Sheets(data_sheet1).Range(Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(1, iCol), Sheets(data_sheet1).Cells(iRow, iCol)).Copy Destination:=Sheets(target_sheet).Cells(1, TargetCol)
    End If

Next iCol 'Move to the next column until all columns are read

End Sub
```

---

Can you help me with this?

Thanks,
Ciaran

Comment: Your macro doesnt have the code for editing header, you need to have a proper list of the header amendments and then add those to the code...you can try by using Macro recorder within Excel to record and amend the code according to the requirement..

Answer (score 2):

I have found that converting the data on the sheet to a table makes it a lot better to program for and a lot less messy. If you convert your data to a table with the name 'TableName' and wish to rename a certain column # (2 for this example) to 'Column Title' this would be the code.

```
Dim columnNumber As Long
Dim myTab As ListObject
Set myTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName")
columnNumber = 2
myTab.HeaderRowRange(1, columnNumber) = "Column Title"
```

To run this for multiple columns just run it through a for loop:

```
Dim columnNumber As Long
Dim myTab As ListObject
Set myTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName")

For x = 1 To 10  ' For Columns 1 through 10
    columnNumber = x
    myTab.HeaderRowRange(1, columnNumber) = "Column Title"
Next x
```

Comment: Thanks your reply, that was a great help! Could you tell me, is there a quick way of renaming different columns (eg. 8 columns) at once or would it be best to put the above code in 8 times under different macro's? Sorry i'm very new to VB! Thanks again!

Comment: Run it through a For Loop! I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: This might not be what you need though as it would have the same column title for each column.

Comment: Ya i'm looking to put in different titles for each header. I can always just have the first part of code in separately each time. Thanks!