# (Excel) How Can I Add Worksheet Name as Prefix for Each Column Header?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a header that starts in Column E and might go on for 100+ columns.

**I am trying to change each column header to add a prefix (the name of the "tab" aka. worksheet)** (ie. if Worksheet is called 'Beverage', I'd like each column header to be prefixed with "Beverage -")

I will be running script across multiple sheets, so am trying to find a way to reference the current sheet name.

---

**Before:** (For Worksheet "Beverage")

### [image]

**After:** (For Worksheet "Beverage". Note: Columns don't need to be resized, just did it to demonstrate)
[image]

---

I've tried adapting code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231100/excel-vb-re-ordering-renaming-columns), however I can't get it to work.

**Here is the code I have so far (non-working):**

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Prefix()

Dim columnNumber As Long, x As Integer

Dim myTab As ListObject
Set myTab = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(rows.Count, 1)

For x = 5 To rows.Count  ' For Columns E through last header cell with value
    columnNumber = x
    myTab.HeaderRowRange(1, columnNumber) = ActiveSheet.Name
Next x

End Sub
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong with my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more clear with you question? It si vague and confusing... You got the headers From E1 to E100 and plus... And you want to change every header with the name of the sheet??? That all you need??? All you want????

Comment: You seem to be attempting to change things in a list object, which is a specific object in a worksheet and does not represent the data in the sheet...

Comment: @ElbertV I just want to add the name of the Worksheet ("Beverage - ") in front of each column (aluminum, tablecraft, indoor, etc). So final result would be "Beverage - aluminum", "Beverage - tablecraft", etc.

Comment: Well tell me if my answer is right...

Comment: @ElbertV Yes, just ran it and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help you...

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Prefix_v2()
    Dim h 'to store the last columns/header
    Dim rngHeaders As Range 'the whole range with the headers from E1 to x1
    Dim i 'just and index
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'the sheet where you want the job done

    h = Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header
    Set rngHeaders = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(1, h)) 'the range with the headers E = column 5
    'Cells 1 5 = E1
    'Cells 1 h = x1 where x is the last column with data
    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'the sheet with the data, _
                          'and we take the name of that sheet to do the job

    For Each i In rngHeaders 'for each cell in the headers (every cells in row 1)
        i.Value = sht.Name & " - " & i.Value
        'set the value "sheet_name - cell_value" in every cell
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you need any emprovement please tell me... I'm not sure if I get the real idea of what you need.

**Edit #1**

Use this in a regular module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub goForEverySheet()
    Dim noSht01 As Worksheet 'store the first sheet
    Dim noSht02 As Worksheet 'store the second sheet
    Dim sht 'just a tmp var

    Set noSht01 = Sheets("AA") 'the first sheet
    Set noSht02 = Sheets("Word Frequency") 'the second sheet

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False
    For Each sht In Worksheets ' for each sheet inside the worksheets of the workbook
        If sht.Name <> noSht01.Name And sht.Name <> noSht02.Name Then
        'IF sht.name is different to AA AND sht.name is diffent to WordFrecuency THEN

        'TIP:
        'If Not sht.Name = noSht01.Name And Not sht.Name = noSht02.name Then 'This equal
        'IF (NOT => negate the sentence) sht.name is NOT equal to noSht01 AND
        '                                sht.name is NOT equal to noSht02 THEN

            sht.Activate 'go to that Sheet!
            Worksheet_Name_Prefix_v3 'run the code
        End If '
    Next sht 'next one please!
    appTGGL
End Sub


Sub Worksheet_Name_Prefix_v3()
    Dim h 'to store the last columns/header
    Dim rngHeaders As Range 'the whole range with the headers from E1 to x1
    Dim i 'just and index
    Dim sht As Worksheet 'the sheet where you want the job done

    h = Range("E1").End(xlToRight).Column 'find the last column with the data/header
    Set rngHeaders = Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(1, h)) 'the range with the headers E = column 5
    'Cells 1 5 = E1
    'Cells 1 h = x1 where x is the last column with data
    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'the sheet with the data, _
                          'and we take the name of that sheet to do the job

    For Each i In rngHeaders 'for each cell in the headers (every cells in row 1)
        i.Value = sht.Name & " - " & i.Value
        'set the value "sheet_name - cell_value" in every cell
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub
```

Your code was not running because, you do not use this line `sht.Activate` you say, `for every sheet in the workbook do this`, but you not say to go to every sheet, and the the code run *`n`* times in the same sheet (as many sheets there in the workbook less two). But if you say, `for every sheet do this`, AND got to each of one of that sheets and do this (less that two sheets) you will get whay you want

Comment: Thank you for the code and especially the comments, it really helps for someone new to VBA like me

Comment: btw, would you happen to know how to get this script to run across all sheets (except 2) in my workbook? Here is my attempt at modifying the code you gave me, but it still only works for the local sheet: http://www.savwire.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/SOLVED_Worksheet_Name_Prefix_v2.txt

Comment: I would just put it inside a regular module, run it once, and it would run across all worksheets (Except worksheets "AA" and "Word Frequency")

Comment: Thank you @Elbert Villarreal! It works, though I had to replace ' If sht.Name <> noSht01 And sht.Name <> noSht02 Then' with 'If sht.Name <> "AA" And sht.Name <> "Word Frequency" Then' because I was getting 'error 438 Object doesn't support this property', and I couldn't get my microsoft office 2010 to update. But the code works perfectly, especially how it's separated, I will use that template for other scripts as well. Many thanks, muy amable